# postgresql pg_notify there is no assignment for result data in the request

Tags: postgresql, notifications, plpgsql

I want to get notifications using `pg_notify` function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_task_notify()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
   payload text;

BEGIN           
   SELECT pg_notify('tasks', 'payload');
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION add_task_notify()
OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER add_task_event_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_task_notify();
```

But I get the error (is translated from my native language - not exactly error, which you can get in English): `There is no assignment for result data in the request`. What's wrong?

Comment: To get the *original English error message*, run `set lc_messages = 'C'` in your session. This helps to find related answers quickly: `ERROR: query has no destination for result data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original error message is:

> `ERROR:  query has no destination for result data`.

Use [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html) instead of `SELECT`:

```
...
BEGIN           
    PERFORM pg_notify('tasks', 'payload');
    RETURN NEW;
END;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I should use this:

```
PERFORM pg_notify('tasks', 'payload');
```